# Получения списка папок в Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Необходимо получить список папок в директории. При использовании `fs.readdirSync` выводит список всех файлов, но нужны только папки, прошу помочь. Так же в папке есть файлы без расширения, поэтому проверка расширения не спасёт.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99911/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-alexey-ten).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методу [`readdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) можно передать опцию `withFileTypes: true`, в таком случае он возвращает массив объектов типа [`fs.Dirent`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dirent) у которых есть метод `.isDirectory()`.

```
fs.readdirSync("C:\\", { withFileTypes: true })
    .filter(d => d.isDirectory())
    .map(d => d.name);
```